# Excel PivotTable from Cube: How to get a flat table?

Tags: excel

I'm importing data from a SQL Cube and have several row labels I'd like to show. Is there a way to NOT have the hierarchical view? (aka no plus signs for the first row values, and instead show the second row label's value next to the first row labels, etc.) I'd like to see ALL data without it being hidden or aggregated together.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Figured it out...

It's under PivotTable Tools > Design > Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form

Comment: Also, in the same `Report Layout` menu, select "Repeat Item Labels".